# Change images from square to rectangle

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I am using Magento 1.9 and the RWD theme. My product images are rectangle, being taller than they are wide, however Magento shows them as square. How do I change this?

My largest image size is 1000x600 (Height x Width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image->resize

```
/**
 * Schedule resize of the image
 * $width *or* $height can be null - in this case, lacking dimension will be calculated.
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image
 * @param int $width
 * @param int $height
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image
 */
public function resize($width, $height = null)
{
    $this->_getModel()->setWidth($width)->setHeight($height);
    $this->_scheduleResize = true;
    return $this;
}
```

So resize by `->keepFrame(true)->resize(null, 300)`

Comment: It took me a while to figure this out, but I had to edit list.phtml, find the code for //Grid Mode, and change ->resize($_imgSize) to ->resize(200, $_imgSize) to get correct proportions for my images. Putting 'null' instead of 200 resulted in no change to images.

Comment: Ah, you should also set `->keepFrame(true)` before calling resize. Than the width is automatically calculated

Comment: Thanks! I actually had to use ->keepFrame(false), but it works perfect. The images now match how they look on list mode.